# Coupling complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

After several calculations I end up with two complex functions:

$$g(z)=zA(z)+\overline{z}A(\overline{z})+z^{-1}B(z)+\overline{z^{-1}}B(\bar{z})$$

and

$$s(z)=izA(iz)+\overline{iz}A(\overline{iz})+(iz)^{-1}B(iz)+\overline{(iz)^{-1}}B(\overline{(iz)})$$

where $z\in \mathbf{c}$ and $A$ and $B$ are functions defined in the complex field.

i was wondering if there is any way to couple them by simply considering the expressions proposed above (besides the trivial $s(z)=g(iz)$).

Thanks

Comment: $g(z)=s(iz)$ is a very strong relation, showing that $g$ and $s$ are essentially the same function. So you are actually after a couplingof $g$ with itself. Without more information on $A$ and $B$, the only property I see is $g(z)=g(\overline z)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have asked another question since I realized the final result was different from this. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128803/coupling-real-functions