# Coupling real functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I ended up with the following two real functions, that are actually the cosine and sine Fourier transform of other more complicated functions:

$$g(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega}\left\{\frac{4\omega}{4\omega\delta^2+i}A\left(\frac{4\omega}{4\omega\delta^2+i}\right)+\frac{4\omega}{4\omega\delta^2-i}A\left(\frac{4\omega}{4\omega\delta^2-i}\right)-\frac{4\omega\delta^2+i}{4\omega}B\left(\frac{4\omega}{4\omega\delta^2+i}\right)-\frac{4\omega\delta^2-i}{4\omega}B\left(\frac{4\omega}{4\omega\delta^2-i}\right)\right\}$$

and

$$s(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega}\left\{\frac{4\omega}{1+i4\omega\delta^2}A\left(\frac{4\omega}{1+i4\omega\delta^2}\right)+\frac{4\omega}{1-i4\omega\delta^2}A\left(\frac{4\omega}{1-i4\omega\delta^2}\right)-\frac{1+i4\omega\delta^2}{4\omega}B\left(\frac{4\omega}{1+i4\omega\delta^2}\right)-\frac{1-i4\omega\delta^2}{4\omega}B\left(\frac{4\omega}{1-i4\omega\delta^2}\right)\right\}$$

where $\omega>0$ the Fourier frequency, $\delta>0$ a real constant, $A$ and $B$ converging series (in the form of a generalized geometric series).

Besides the expression of $A$ and $B$, I was looking for a way to couple $g$ and $s$ using the parameter $\omega$.

Any hint on how to proceed?
Thanks

Comment: I think the summands $g$ and $s$ only differ by a factors of $1/i$ or so?

Comment: @flawr not really, otherwise $g$ or $s$ would not be real.